# c++ How to properly use copy constructors with class templates

Tags: c++

I would not ask this, but after about 5 hours of googling and digging through stack, text books, and youtube videos, I am still stuck.  Here is the code I am working with (yes its pretty bad, I am just learning C++)  If you make it to the bottom, you will see that I am having trouble getting the copy constructor to actually make another object of type SimpleVector.  The last line shows where I am trying to use the copy constructor I created to make mySV2 from mySV, and then demonstrate that it happened by using the print function for the new object.

Thanks again for the help and putting up with my newb question.  I honestly believe that feedback is the breakfast of champions (and less crappy coders) so please fire away and know that I will be eternally grateful (or at least for the duration of this class) for your assistance.

```
template <class T>
class SimpleVector {
public:
    T* myarray;
    T* temparr;
    //constructors
    SimpleVector() {
        size = 0;
        myarray = NULL;
    }

    SimpleVector(int sz) {
        size = sz;
        myarray = new T[size];
    }

    //**** Copy Constructor ****
    SimpleVector(const SimpleVector& sv) {
        size = sv.size;
        dataType = sv.dataType;
        temparr = new T[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            temparr[i] = sv.myarray[i];
        }
        myarray = temparr;
    }

};

int main() {
        int howMany = 5;
        SimpleVector<string> mySV(howMany);
        for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
            cout << "Enter item " << (i + 1) << ": ";
            cin >> mySV.myarray[i];
        }
    mySV.print();

    template<class T>
    SimpleVector<T> mySV2(mySV);

    mySV2.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of irrelevant code, can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us instead?

Comment: The copy constructor is the one thing that isn't a problem in this. You're trying to use objects outside of their scope, and you're trying to declare a template variable inside main. And you don't have matching open and close braces.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I tried to clean it up to make it easier to get through.  If I did not put the template class definition back into main, it seemed like the attempt to use the copy constructor just threw an undefined type error.  Adding it in there resolved that, but created more problems.  Thank you for the help.  I hope me cutting it down has made it easier to get through.

Comment: In the declaration of `mySV2`, remove the `template` part.

Comment: This still doesn't compile. `SimpleVector<string> mySV2(mySV);` is all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code. The line `temparr = new T[size];` creates a memory leak as `temparr` is not deleted in the destructor. `temparr` is actually not necessary for the copy constructor:

```
SimpleVector(const SimpleVector& sv){
    size = sv.size;
    dataType = sv.dataType;
    myarray = new T[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        myarray[i] = sv.myarray[i];
    }
}
```

If copying pointers of basic types I would also suggest using the [std::copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) function from the `<utility>` header. You should also consider [the rule of three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) when dealing with copy constructors.

The next issue is found in the main:

```
template<class T>
SimpleVector<T> mySV2(mySV);
```

Here you need to specify the type of `T` to construct the object. Your class member `dataType` cannot specify the type of your newly created object. You should change it to

```
SimpleVector<std::string> mySV2(mySV);
```

After adding a `void print()` member function and the members `size_t size` and `std::string dataType` the code executed correctly.

Comment: The end of your copy constructor leaks the old array, and deletes the new one, which `myarray` then points to.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Yes obviously. I fixed the error in my code example. I didnt't notice as the code still executed correctly. Should have gone with `std::copy` all along. Thanks for the heads-up.